# story about an ark on land demonstrating time dilation

Tags: story-identification, time, time-dilation

I'm looking for a story about an ark on land where the people who live in the ark are pulling the ark along.  If they travel forward of the ark, time speeds up, if they travel in a reverse direction to the ark, time slows down.

Comment: Did the story have anything to do with aliens and alien abductions?

Answer (score 10):

This is [Inverted World](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_World) by Christopher Priest.

As chance would have it, we're discussing this book at our next SciFi reading group meeting. I first read the book as a 14 year old and I really loved it. I heartily recommend it to 14 year olds of all ages!

Comment: John, you are a star.  I've been trying to identify this book for 15 years!  kiss kiss hug hug